# Disable the touchpad buttons from scrolling my mouse

Tags: windows-7, laptop, touchpad

Just bought an HP 4520s. [Everyone with them has the same complaint](http://www.notebookreview.com/default.asp?newsID=5736&review=hp+probook+4520s) that the touchpad buttons pick up hovering fingers, and messes up the scroll.

In the words of the notebookreview.com:

> Making the touchpad button areas a "dead zone" would completely resolve this problem.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Turn the touchpad off.

Answer (score 1):

Try going into the Synaptics control panel (either it has its own, or can be accessed from the "Mouse" control panel - provided you have the original installation) and see if you can change the sensitivity of the buttons, or diable them altogether. I had some issues with the mouse pointer in my laptop and the mouse control panel saved me.

Another thing you may wish to consider is spending $20 on a good, small wireless mouse. I have a Microsoft Bluetooth mouse ($27) that is much more accurate than my touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a synaptics touchpad device, install latest drivers from [download page](http://www.synaptics.com/support/drivers) and increase  palmcheck sensitivity.

From specs, I can see it's a synaptics touchpad.