# Disable buttons area - Asus Elan touchpad

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, touchpad

The problem is that the left-button and right-button are also included in the touch surface.
I found out that this question is common, but I didn't find a solution for Windows(8.1) and Elan(touchpad hardware). Only for Synaptics(another touchpad hardware).
I have tried to download latest driver from Elan. It doesn't have a disabling option for that issue.

Refer:

[xorg: disable touch sensitivity on clickpad button area on Elantech clickpad](https://superuser.com/questions/553160/xorg-disable-touch-sensitivity-on-clickpad-button-area-on-elantech-clickpad)

[Disable the touchpad buttons from scrolling my mouse](https://superuser.com/questions/228166/disable-the-touchpad-buttons-from-scrolling-my-mouse)

http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/elan-touchpad-any-way-to-disable-certain-area.730285/

Thanks!